# How to highlight multiple bar using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I want to highlight the max value and 2 other bars. Can anyone help me with this, thank you!![image]

```
#Figure size
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 8))

#Group by position and find the mean salary
df.groupby("Position")["Salary"].mean()

#Plot bar graph
ax = df.groupby("Position")["Salary"].mean()

#Highlight max value bar
ax.plot.bar(color=np.where(ax==ax.max(), '#ff9999','cadetblue'))

#Axis label
plt.xlabel("Position",fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Salary",fontsize=12)
plt.title("Wages for different job functions", fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of bar graphs and set the color of the desired location. In the following example, besides setting a special color for the largest value in your code, you have also set the fourth to red.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

bars = ax.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', color=np.where(performance == performance.max(),'#ff9999','cadetblue'))
ax.set_xticks(y_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(people)
ax.set_ylabel('Salary')
ax.set_title("Wages for different job functions", fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)

bars[3].set_color("red")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The basis of my answer is a modification of the sample in the official [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barh-py). The sample graph is a horizontal bar graph, so please note that the names of the x and y axes are wrong in the code.

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable. Do you know whats the reason?

Comment: Did you run it with my code? In your code, ax is the name of the data frame, and you are drawing a graph in a pandas plot. In my code's matplotlib, ax is a graph object, so I think that's the cause.